# jQuery sortable serialize returns blank when trying to sort a table

Tags: jquery, sass, jquery-ui-sortable, css-tables

Seen similar posts on this, but the solutions I've seen don't work for me.  I'm trying to make table rows sortable.  When I try to serialize, I get nothing in the console.

Here's the table. (Sass)

```
    %table#list
      %tbody
        %tr.item
          %td.order 1.
          %td.name The best list item ever
        %tr.item
          %td.order 2.
          %td.name Another great list.
```

Here's the coffee script

```
$("#list tbody").sortable update: ->
  order = $("#list tbody").sortable("serialize")
  console.log order
```

Here's the css for the table

```
table#list {
    float: left;
    td.order {
        width: 18px;
        vertical-align: top;
    }
    tr:hover .controls {
            display:inline;
    }
}
```

What's going on?  Just getting blank in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`serialize` method](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-serialize) documentation:

> It works **by default by looking at the `id` of each item** in the format
>   `"setname_number"`, and it spits out a hash like
>   `"setname[]=number&setname[]=number"`.

So your items needs to have ids

```
%table#list
      %tbody
        %tr.item#item_1
          %td.order 1.
          %td.name The best list item ever
        %tr.item#item_2
          %td.order 2.
          %td.name Another great list.
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/27tqK/).